# multi language support toogle switch not showing

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, voyager

Although I went according to the Voyager documentation, the en/tr translation tool does not come, where could I have gone wrong?

config/voyager.php

```
'multilingual' => [
    /*
     * Set whether or not the multilingual is supported by the BREAD input.
     */
    'enabled' => true,

    /*
     * Select default language
     */
    'default' => 'tr',

    /*
     * Select languages that are supported.
     */
    'locales' => [
        'en',
        'tr',
    ],
],
```

Ceviriler.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use TCG\Voyager\Traits\Translatable;


class Cevirler extends Model
{
    use Translatable;
    protected $translatable = ['text'];
}
```

Result
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with `root/project composer update`